# SQL Server performance issue with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

There is a performance issue with a SQL query. 
This is my query

```
declare @siteId int,    
@totalCount int

 SELECT @totalCount = COUNT(DISTINCT pro.product_id)
    FROM product AS pro 
    INNER JOIN product_to_category AS proCat ON pro.product_id = proCat.product_id
    INNER JOIN product_to_vendor proVen ON  pro.product_id = proVen.product_id
WHERE pro.site_id = @siteId 
    AND pro.product_type <> 3
print @totalCount
```

It is take 6 seconds to execute..

when I remove parameters as follows

```
@totalCount int

SELECT @totalCount = COUNT(DISTINCT pro.product_id)
FROM product AS pro 
INNER JOIN product_to_category AS proCat ON pro.product_id = proCat.product_id
INNER JOIN product_to_vendor proVen ON  pro.product_id = proVen.product_id
WHERE pro.site_id = 28
AND pro.product_type <> 3
print @totalCount
```

and execute query again, it takes only 2 seconds.

is there a method to improve performance of an query like this? 
why it takes time to assign values to parameters?
any comments....

Comment: do you have any indexing on your tables?

Comment: @Tharaka, Did you try rerunning the parameterised version of the query immediately *after* running the hard-coded version? If so, how long did it take?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a parameter it is a variable.

SQL Server does not sniff the values of variables so it does not know at compile time that the value it will contain is `28`

Add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of your query to get it to recompile the statement after the variable's value has been assigned and it should generate a more suitable execution plan.

Comment: I have tried OPTION (RECOMPILE). It is good for sub stored procedures bu not for nested stored procedures.Is there any other solution?

Comment: you add it to the end of the query `... WHERE pro.site_id = @siteId AND pro.product_type <> 3 OPTION (RECOMPILE)`